# React app behind nginx reverse proxy css is text/plain. CSS not applied

Tags: reactjs, nginx, https

I have a react app with a css file. It is behind `nginx/1.23.0`. It's a nginx `container`.

App loads fine but without css applied.

css is loaded but:

[image: css_not_working]

I have tried with `include mime.types` which is at same folder as `nginx.conf`.

btw. This all works with only `http` nginx proxy but not with `https`.

Full nginx.conf

```
events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http{

    server {
            listen 443 ssl http2;
            server_name example.com;

            ssl_certificate /certs/certnew.cer;
            ssl_certificate_key /certs/private.key;

            ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:1m;
            ssl_session_timeout 10m;
            ssl_protocols  TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
            ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!CAMELLIA:!DES:!MD5:!PSK:!RC4;
            ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

            access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log;
            error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log error;

            location / {
                root /usr/share/nginx/html;
                index index.html index.htm;
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
            }

            location /api/ {
                proxy_pass http://backend:8000;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

            }

            location /socket-traffic/ {
                proxy_pass http://backend:8001;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
            }

            error_page 404 /404.html;
                location = /40x.html {
            }

            error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
                location = /50x.html {
            }

    }
}
```

Comment: Seems like it was only with chrome. Now I cleared cache and put ```include mime.types;``` and seems like it is working. I'll answer to my own question if what happened does not appear again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, the problem seemed to be chrome cache and lack of `include mime.types;` where it first loaded the css as `text\plain` and it did not change anymore even after adding `mime.types`. Only after cache purge